# ASP.NET Core 7.0 Localization not working

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, localization

I'm having trouble configuring localization in my asp.net 7.0 MVC project.
Configuration:

```
.AddLocalization(opts => opts.ResourcesPath = "Resources")
```

then

```
CultureInfo[] supportedCultures = new[]
        {
            new CultureInfo("en-US"),
            new CultureInfo("bg-BG")
        };

        mvcBuilder
            .AddViewLocalization(LanguageViewLocationExpanderFormat.Suffix)
            .AddDataAnnotationsLocalization();

        mvcBuilder
            .Services
            .Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture(culture: "en-US", uiCulture: "en-US");
                options.SupportedCultures = supportedCultures;
                options.SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures;
            });
```

This is called before

```
.AddRazorPages();
```

And at the end

```
app.UseRequestLocalization(app.Services.GetRequiredService<IOptions<RequestLocalizationOptions>>().Value);
```

I have installed Microsoft.Extensions.Localization nuget.
I have two resource files in folder Resources

- Controllers.HomeController.bg-BG.resx
- Controllers.HomeController.en-US.resx

In both resources there is entry "title" with some values
Injected IStringLocalizer into HomeController but everytime it returns only "title", used it like this:

```
this.stringLocalizer["title"].Value
```

After hours of trial and error I really can't seem to find what's the problem.

Comment: How did you ensure that the view/page actually ran under `bg-BG` when you tested it? To be sure just add a temporary `<h2>@System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.Name</h2>` to your view.

Comment: @OliverWeichhold this returns en-US but `stringLocalizer["title"].Value;` in the Controller still returns only "title", the value for key title in the resource file is not "title".

Comment: Is the build action for `Controllers.HomeController.en-US.resx` = `EmbeddedResource` and `Custom Tool` = `PublicResXFileCodeGenerator` ?

Comment: Yes, for both..

Comment: Wait a minute. What is `stringLocalizer` ?

Comment: `IStringLocalizer<HomeController>`

Comment: You've mixed up two localization technologies. `IStringLocalizer` is not fed by .resx files. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Comment: I red the documentation several times and still don't get it. That is `IStringLocalizer ` fed by? And with .resx files how can I use them in views and code?

Comment: I doubt many people use it because it is so confusing.

Comment: Ok then how to use localization with resource files I can't seem to find a solution that works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to be mixing up two different localization techniques. The .resx resource files is the classic .NET technique for localization while the `IStringLocalizer` based approach has been added in .NET Core. Fortunately, it is still perfectly fine to utilize .resx resources .NET Core Views/Pages.

Add a using statement at the top of your view. Make sure that the namespace matches the actual C# namespace of your resource. The example below assumes that the default namespace of the project is `WebApp` and the .resx files live inside a `Resources` folder:

```
@using WebApp.Resources
```

Referencing a resource string inside your view is straight forward:

```
<h2>@Controllers_HomeController.title</h2>
```

NOTE: The underscore in Controllers_HomeController is caused your use of a `.` in the resource filename, which would cause problems with the strongly typed generated class inside the corresponding `Controllers_HomeController.Designer.cs`

Comment: I'll try using the classic way, but every tutorial I red and watch shows using `IStringLocalizer ` with resource files and apparently for them it works. How can I store the translations if I want to use `IStringLocalizer ` instead of the classic way?

Comment: Hey, Oliver Weichhold!
I hope you are doing fine. I am using Portable Object Localization it is working fine in development mode but when I publish it, the localization does not work at all.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was something to do with the namespaces, changed the default namespace and it works now.

Answer (score -1):

This answer is applicable for .NET 6,7 and maybe previous versions as well.

In project properties, **Root Namespace** (Default Namespace) must be the same as **Assembly Name** for the solution to detect the **resx** file by default.

This is required for the following code to work:

```cs
var assemblyName = new AssemblyName(type.GetTypeInfo().Assembly.FullName);
_localizer = factory.Create("SharedResource", assemblyName.Name);
```